# Spigot Plugin from tutorial failing to run

Tags: javascript, java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to run a simple minecraft plugin I've built through a local spigot server. the plugins  is

- Main.java

```
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
   @Override
    public void onEnable() {
       getLogger().info("onEnable has been invoked!");
       // TODO Insert logic to be performed when the plugin is enabled
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("onDisable has been invoked!");
        // TODO Insert logic to be performed when the plugin is disabled
    }
}
```

- plugin.yml

```
name: Kolo
version: 1.0
author: will

commands:
  Hello:
```

Everytime I export the project as a jar to the plugins folder of my server and run my server it gives me this

```
[20:31:29 INFO]: Set PluginClassLoader as parallel capable
[20:31:29 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins/Kolo.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `me.will.Kolo'
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:66) ~[minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
```

Can someone explain this to me? Idk if the info part of the code means anything but I searched it up and couldn't really decipher any instructions on how to go about doing what it says. Im still learning java and I feel like its mostly me forgetting a simple thing but I wanted to check on here to see if maybe one of you could clarify for me so I'll understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the "main" attribute in your plugin.yml file.

In case your folder structure is like "me/will/Kolo/Main.java", it should be like this:

- plugin.yml

```
name: Kolo
version: 1.0
author: will
main: me.will.Kolo.Main
commands:
  Hello:
```